# Explain about the nature of output of the code?

Tags: c, for-loop

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  for(j = i+1, i=1; i<=5; j++, i++)
     printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 66
2 67
3 68
4 69
5 70
```

Can Anyone explain about the nature of output of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `i`, `j` are not initialized at the time of declaration.
In for loop you assign `j = i + 1`  So `j` remains garbage value whereas `i` assigned  `1` ,

in for loop you increment `i`, `j` and printf values. `i` increment from `1` to `5`, and `j` from a initial garbage value (that is 66 in your output) to `initial garbage + 5`.

**Edit** On the basis of comments:

> If you don't assign an initial value upon declaration the variable will be pointing at an address that may contain previously **used data from another application**(or any last used).

**Before allocating memory in runtime system does not clear the memory before allocating (*just to keep system performance high*)** So,default value of the variable is garbage value.

Comment: if i run this code again, then everytime does j take the same garbage value ?

Comment: @AmanSingh may be same some immediate execution. But different thermostatically garbage value are unclenup for performance purpose

Comment: Can u please explain when it could be different or how will it depend ?

Comment: @AmanSingh try to do random for on your system, close your shell then reopen it. then run again your code, (you can poweroff your system then start again you will get a different value then for sure )

Answer (score 5):

i is unitialized when you set j=i+1.  So j (initially) could be almost anything.

Comment: why is it is starting from 66 only ?

Comment: Am I the only one who can't even run this?

Comment: @AmanSingh it's probably something that gets allocated and freed as you build and/or run your project

Comment: perhaps it's drunk (and actually, it's 0x42 in hex).

Comment: It runs. I get 1,1, 2,2,  etc.  Initial value of j is not guaranteed. Could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

j is assigned the value of i even before i is assigned = 1. So i here can be any arbitrary value provided to it by the OS. In the above case the value assigned to i by the OS was 66. This arbitrary value could be different on varying systems.